# Does the client need SP metadata when implementing SSO using OneLogin?

Tags: single-sign-on, metadata, saml, onelogin

I'm doing a technical assessment for a job interview. It's called on me to walk through implementing a client using OneLogin (IDP) into our software (SP) with SSO.

The activity is asking me to include 3 things:

1. Service Provider
2. Identity Provider
3. Generate and distribute the sp metadata to the client

I'm using https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php to generate the metadata but I'm wondering what the purpose of this doing this when this SP is already a verified app on OneLogin?

OneLogin's knowledge base [here](https://onelogin.service-now.com/kb_view_customer.do?sysparm_article=KB0010398) doesn't indicate the need for the SP metadata to implement. It doesn't even call for any SP entity's or endpoints. It seems like I would need the idp metadata as the endpoints use a unique value but not the opposite. So am I right in assuming that generating and sending the client the SP metadata is useless? Or is there a reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Onelogin catalog app, you often don't need any instance specific metadata from the SP. The catalog apps are supposed to shortcut and simplify configuring a standards based SAML supporting SP. Some of the Onelogin catalog apps sometimes need some metadata, such as a RelayState parameter as per the SP requirements. If a catalog app doesn't exist and you're building a custom SAML app in Onelogin, you'll need the SP metadata in full.